# Dynamic resource root path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resources, path, devise, root

I am using devise gem for authentication.
I have multiples roles in my project like lab, clinic and then wants to redirect appropriate
home page depending on role. such as
* redirect 'labs#order_status' if logged-in user having 'lab' role.
* redirect 'visit#index' if logged-in user having 'clinic' role.
I can able to achieve above using after_sign_in_path_for method.

But I don't know that how to set these path as resource root_path(like user_root_path )after sign-in
i.e if calling root_path after sign-in which should return
* 'labs#order_status' if logged-in user having 'lab' role.
* 'visit#index' if logged-in user having 'clinic' role.

I can able to set 'static'  resource root_path for logged-in user using authenticated :user method
but I don't know how to set as dynamic

routes.rb

```
scope :path => '/clinic', :controller => :visits do
   match '/' => :index, :as => :clinic_root
end

scope :path => '/lab', :controller => :labs do
   match '/' => :order_status, :as => :lab_root
end

authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'lab_visits#new'
end

devise_scope :user do 
  root :to => "devise/sessions#new"
end

unauthenticated do
  as :user do
      root :to => 'devise/sessions#new'
  end
end

root :to => "devise/sessions#new"
```

application.rb

```
protected
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    case current_user.type
    when "LAB"
        lab_root_path
    when "CLINIC"
        clinic_root_path
    else
        super  
    end
  end
```

Comment: See [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devise).
it answered by @vonconrad.

Comment: I have solved this issue by using rails advance constraint (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints) and warden(request.env['warden'].user)